# procedure to check date exists in the entire table between a range

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures

I have my following procedure

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dashboard_history`(fromdate date,todate date,empcode int)
BEGIN
Declare startdate date;
Declare enddate date;
set @id=empcode;
set @st=fromdate;
set @et=todate;
 SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 30000000;
 #SELECT min(from_date) into startdate FROM requestor_employees WHERE emp_code=@id;
 #SELECT max(to_date) into enddate FROM requestor_employees WHERE emp_code=@id;
call fill_calendar(@st,@et);

SELECT year(datefield) AS alloc_year
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='January') then pm.project_name END) as 'Jan'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='February') then pm.project_name END) as 'Feb'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='March') then pm.project_name END) as'Mar'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='April') then pm.project_name END)  as 'Apr'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='May') then pm.project_name END) as 'May'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='June') then pm.project_name END)  as 'Jun'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date)  and monthname(datefield)='July') then pm.project_name END) as 'Jul'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='August') then pm.project_name END) as'Aug'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='September') then pm.project_name END) as 'Sep'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='October') then pm.project_name END) as'Oct'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='November') then pm.project_name END) as 'Nov'
 ,group_concat(distinct case when( year(datefield)>=year(re.from_date) and year(datefield)<=year(re.to_date) and month(datefield)>=month(re.from_date) and month(datefield)<=month(re.to_date) and monthname(datefield)='December') then pm.project_name END) as 'Dec' from calendar c left outer join requestor_employees re inner join requestor_master rm on re.req_id=rm.req_id inner join project_master pm on rm.project_auto_id=pm.project_auto_id inner join employee_master em on pm.pm_emp_code=em.emp_code on re.emp_code=@id and re.flag in("NA","MA","ND","MD") group by alloc_year;
END
```

I get my desired output but i face the following issue 
Lets say for eg: from_date is 2016-05-15 and to_date is 2016-09-30 the next from_date is 2016-09-30 and to_date is 2017-03-31.I don't get my output for the months ranging from 2016-09-30 to 2017-03-31.
Should I add another condition?How can i fix this issue?.Someone help me thanks in advance

Comment: friends waiting for your valuable reply. I am stuck with this.Help me please

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And, to the extent that this problem is a display issue, seriously consider handling that aspect of the problem in application code.

Comment: left outer join requestor_employees re is missing an on statement.

Comment: adding on left outer join on condition gives unexpected output

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a business date/accounting period which doesn't match calender date?